# What's the difference between Ki and IC50?

Tags: biochemistry, enzyme-kinetics

I have just read this post at researchgate: "[How to calculate experimental binding free energy from the IC50 value](http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_experimental_binding_free_energy_from_the_IC50_value)"

I am not be very sure about what the difference is between K<sub>i</sub> and IC<sub>50</sub>. Could anybody explain?

Answer (score 5):

In biochemistry the K<sub>i</sub> is the [dissociation constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_constant) of a complex and molecules bound to it. It is a measure for the  functional strength of the inhibitor. This can for example be an enzyme and its substrate, the K<sub>i</sub> defines the stability of the complex.

The [IC<sub>50</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC50) on the other hand is the halfmaximal inhibitory concentration of a substance on a biochemical process. This can be an inhibitor of an enzyme. 
See this figure (from the Wikipedia article on the IC<sub>50</sub>):

[image]

The K<sub>i</sub> plays an important role in the calculation of the IC<sub>50</sub>, as it defines the strength of the enzyme-inhibitor complex.

Comment: I don't know if I'd call the Ki a measure of functional strength, I think it measures binding. It might be possible for a ligand to bind a protein tightly, giving it a low Ki, but not inhibit it, giving it a high IC50. But this situation probably only exists with allosteric binding sites, where a ligand can bind in a location separate from the active site.